# Escape special character in variable

Tags: csvsimple

I like to print a list of names and email addresses in LaTeX.
These come from a CSV file and I read it with `csvsimple` package.
A problem arised with email addresses like foo_bar@foo.bar... (underscore)...
If I have the address in a variable like \email, I get en error "missing $ inserted" and it won't compile...

Is there a way to escape all special characters in a variable?

The code of the line looks like this:

```
\href{mailto:\emaili}{\emaili}\newline
```

Thank you very much for your help.
  Daniel.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As a new member, it is recommended to visit these pages https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx and https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour to be informed and also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 to know about Minimal Example. 
So I recommand to edit your question if a minimal example with a small CSV file.